# How to set permissions while uploading files using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to upload a file (docx file) using graph api. I want to understand is it possible to set file level permissions (like the file should not be accessible to anyone).

I tried following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session) but by default the file is accessible to members of the same organization and is opening in view-only mode.

Is this setting configurable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign specific permissions by adding [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0) resources to the file. When not explicitly set, the file will inherit the permissions from the folder to which it was uploaded.

File permission are a relationship and I don't believe this endpoint supports deep-insert (disclosure: I've never attempted it myself). I'm fairly confident you'll need to add your permissions to the `DriveItem` once you've completed the upload session.